# For a prime number p, show that the Frobenius map given by $Frob_p(a) = a^p$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a prime number p, show that the Frobenius map given by $Frob_p(a) = a^p$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb Z_p$.(You may assume that $\binom{m}{n}∈ \mathbb Z$ for each $n, m ∈ \mathbb N$.)

We need to show that Frobenius map is a bijective homomorphism.
$(xy)^p = x^p y^p$ follows from commutativity and
associativity of multiplication.
Expand $(x + y)^p$ using the binomial theorem:
$(x + y)^p = \sum_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}x^k y^{p-k} = x^p+y^p+ \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}x^k y^{p-k}$
For $1 ≤ k ≤ p − 1$,
$$\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$$
where the numerator is divisible by p. From this we see the sum in the above expression is equal to $0$, so
$(x + y)^p= x^p + y^p$
How do I show its bijective?

Comment: Hint: Show it is injective by considering the kernel. Then use that both domain and codomain have the same finite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done so far is great.

In order to show that the Frobenius morphism is bijective, it is sufficient to show it is injective, since $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a finite set (and every injective function from a finite set to itself is bijective).

> You can show that the kernel of the Frobenius morphism is trivial : if $a^p = 0$ in  $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, then $a=0$ because  $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ is a domain, as $p$ is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's Theorem, we have $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$ for all $p$. So the Frobenius map, thought of as a function from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z_p}$, is the identity map.